# Edit Form shows no data and fails to save when posted to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My edit form is without error but the data that I want to edit is not shown.

I try to insert new information inside the edit form, thinking that the information might change, but nothing happened.

Below is my code.

**edit_item.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php require('header.php'); 
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  
  <!-- css js -->
  <?php include "layout/cssjs.php";?>
 </head>
 
 <!-- check login session -->
 
 <body class="no-sidebar">
 <?php
 $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
 $nama = isset($_GET['nama']) ? $_GET['nama'] : '';
 $noIc = isset($_GET['noIc']) ? $_GET['noIc'] : '';
 $gred = isset($_GET['gred']) ? $_GET['gred'] : '';
 $unit = isset($_GET['unit']) ? $_GET['unit'] : '';
 $catatan = isset($_GET['catatan']) ? $_GET['catatan'] : '';
 $status = isset($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : '';

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM datastaf WHERE id = '$id'");
 $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

 ?>
  <div id="page-wrapper">

   <!-- Header -->

   <!-- Main -->
    <article id="main">

     <header class="special container">
      <h2>Update <strong>Student</strong></h2>
      <p>Update Student Details</p>
     </header>

     <!-- Content -->
      <section class="wrapper style4 container">

       <!-- Content -->
        <div class="content">
         <section>
          <form method="post">
           <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
             <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
             <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama" value="<?php echo $nama; ?>" required />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
             <input type="text" name="noIc" placeholder="Noic" value="<?php echo $noIc; ?>" required />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
             <input type="text" name="gred" placeholder="Gred" value="<?php echo $gred; ?>" required />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row 50%">
            <div class="6u 12u(mobile)">
             <input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="Unit" value="<?php echo $unit; ?>" required />
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row 50%">
           <div class="2u 12u(mobile)">
            <input type="text" name="tkuatkuasa" placeholder="TKUATKUASA" value="T/KUATKUASA" readonly />
           </div>
           <div class="6u 10u(mobile)">
            <input type="date" name="catatan" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="<?php echo $catatan; ?>" required />
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="12u">
             <ul class="buttons">
              <li><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
              <li><input type="submit" name="update" class="special" value="Update" /></li>
             </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
          </form>
         </section>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
   
   <!-- Scripts -->
   <?php include "layout/script.php"; ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

**header.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Record Management System</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Charisma, a fully featured, responsive, HTML5, Bootstrap admin template.">
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Usman">

    <!-- The styles -->
    <link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/charisma-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'>
    <link href='bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/colorbox/example3/colorbox.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/responsive-tables/responsive-tables.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/jquery.noty.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/noty_theme_default.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/elfinder.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/elfinder.theme.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/jquery.iphone.toggle.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/animate.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- The HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- The fav icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>
<?php require ('include/database.php'); ?>
<?php require ('session.php'); ?>
<?php if (!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { ?>
    <!-- topbar starts -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left animated flip">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php"> <img alt="Charisma Logo" src="img/logo20.png" class="hidden-xs"/>
                <span>ICT MS</span></a>

            <!-- user dropdown starts -->
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
<?php
 include('include/database.php');
 $user_query=mysql_query("select *  from user where user_id='$id_session'")or die(mysql_error());
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query); {
?>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> <?php echo $row['username']; ?></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <!---<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>-->
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>        <!-- user dropdown ends -->

            <div class="btn-group pull-right theme-container animated tada">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></i><span
                        class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> Change Theme / Skin</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="themes">
                    <li><a data-value="classic" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Classic</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="cerulean" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Cerulean</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="cyborg" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Cyborg</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="simplex" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Simplex</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="darkly" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Darkly</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="lumen" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Lumen</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="slate" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Slate</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="spacelab" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Spacelab</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="united" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> United</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             
            <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav top-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i> Visit Site</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Dropdown <span
                            class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                        <input placeholder="Search" class="search-query form-control col-md-10" name="query"
                               type="text">
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- topbar ends -->
<?php } ?>
<div class="ch-container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php if (!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { ?>

        <!-- left menu starts -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <div class="nav-canvas">
                    <div class="nav-sm nav nav-stacked">

                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked main-menu">
                        <li class="nav-header">Main</li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span> Home</span></a></li>
      
                        <li class="accordion">
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Masterfile</span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="item.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Data Staf</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="addStaf.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> + Staf Baru</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="unit.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Unit</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="contact.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Contact</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="user.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Admin Account</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="accordion">
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Transaction</span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="release.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Releasing</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="return.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Returning</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="accordion">
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Record</span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="list_of_item.php"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> List of Item</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="list_of_client.php"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> List of CLient</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="list_of_transaction.php"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> List of Transaction</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
      <li><a class="ajax-link" href="history.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></i><span> History Log</span></a></li>
     <li><a class="ajax-link" href="ui.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i><span> UI Features</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="form.php"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i><span> Forms</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="chart.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i><span> Charts</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="typography.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></i><span> Typography</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="gallery.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i><span> Gallery</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header hidden-md">Transaction</li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="table.php"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i><span> Tables</span></a></li>
     
                        <li class="accordion">
                            <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i><span> Accordion Menu</span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                <li><a href="#">Child Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child Menu 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="calendar.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i><span> Calendar</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="grid.php"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i><span> Grid</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="tour.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i><span> Tour</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="icon.php"><i
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i><span> Icons</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="error.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i><span> Error Page</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i><span> Login Page</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <label id="for-is-ajax" for="is-ajax"><input id="is-ajax" type="checkbox"> Ajax on menu</label>
     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <!-- left menu ends -->

  <!--      <noscript>
            <div class="alert alert-block col-md-12">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>

                <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a>
                    enabled to use this site.</p>
            </div>
        </noscript>-->

        <div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
            <!-- content starts -->
            <?php } ?>
```

My database table `datastaf` looks like:

[image]

I found no answers at these links:

1. [Basic PHP add, edit delete](https://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/)
2. [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: Put your php first before declaring <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: @Sara if it worked with you, please accept it, if not, please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, You're using method post and trying to retrieve the data using GET, use $_POST instead

e.g.

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are getting the data.

For Example:
$_GET['nama'] should have the value that you are looking for in 
$nama = isset($_GET['nama']) ? $_GET['nama'] : '';

you can use die($_GET['nama']); and check if you are getting the value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already establish a connection, I made some alteration
Feel free to tweak it around.

```html
<?php 
include('db.php');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
  $nama=$_POST[''];
  $noIc=$_POST['noIc'];
  $gred=$_POST['gred'];
  $unit=$_POST['unit'];
  $catatan= $_POST ['catatan'];
  $status= $_POST ['status']
  
  $updated=mysql_query("UPDATE datastaf SET unama='$nama', noIc='$noIc', gred='$gred', unit= '$unit', catatan='$catatan', status='$status' WHERE id='$id'")
or die();
  if($updated)
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  header('Location:item.php');
  }
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit form</title>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  $getselect=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM datastaff WHERE id='$id'");
  while($profile=mysql_fetch_array($getselect))
  {
    $nama=$profile['nama'];
    $noIc=$profile['noIc'];
    $gred=$profile['gred'];
 $unit=$profile['unit'];
    $catatan=$profile['catatan'];
    $status=$profile['status'];
?>


<div class="display">
  <form action="" method="post" name="insertform">
    
 <p>
      <label for="name"  id="preinput"> NAMA : </label>
      <input type="text" name="nama" required placeholder="Nama" 
      value="<?php echo $nama; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p>
    
 <p>
      <label  for="noIc"  id="preinput"> NO IC : </label>
      <input type="number" name="noIc" required placeholder="NO IC" 
      value="<?php echo $noIc; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p>
    
 <p>
      <label for="gred" id="preinput"> GRED : </label>
      <input type="text" name="gred" required placeholder="Gred" 
      value="<?php echo $gred; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p>
    
 <p>
      <label for="gred" id="preinput"> UNIT: </label>
      <input type="text" name="unit" required placeholder="UNIT" 
      value="<?php echo $unit; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p> 
 
 
 <p>
      <label for="gred" id="preinput"> CATATAN : </label>
      <input type="text" name="gred" required placeholder="CATATAN" 
      value="<?php echo $catatan; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p> 
 
 <p>
      <label for="gred" id="preinput"> STATUS : </label>
      <input type="text" name="status" required placeholder="STATUS" 
      value="<?php echo $status; ?>" id="inputid" />
    </p>
 
 <p>
      <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" id="inputid1" />
    </p>
  </form>

  
  </div>
<?php } } ?>
</body>
</html>
```